# Angular 6 Reactive Form field displays [object object] when first shown

Tags: angular

If my form field is defined as

```
occBarcodeProduct: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true, updateOn: 'blur'},
                                    Validators.required,
                                    null
),
```

the field shows the initial value :  `[object object]`

if the definition is reduced to :

```
occBarcodeProduct: new FormControl('',
                                    Validators.required,
                                    null
),
```

the field displays empty, as expected.

I am new to Angular so not sure how to narrow the problem further.

Comment: Try to change '' with null

Comment: Tried but no change.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax gets onupdate and doesn't display [object object]:

occBarcodeProduct: new FormControl('', { validators: Validators.required, asyncValidators: [], updateOn: 'blur' }),

and after the form created, to set disabled :

this.occBarcodeProduct= this.scanForm.controls['occBarcodeProduct'];
this.occBarcodeProduct.disable();

Comment: may as well set the field as disabled on creation -  ```{ validators: Validators.required, disabled: true, ...}```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing null at the end?

You can try this:

```
occBarcodeProduct: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required)
```

Comment: I guess the null as a placeholder for async validators is not necessary.

Comment: Tried without the null but no change.

Comment: are you assigning this value in a form builder object?

Comment: You can refer [this](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#description), they have not told how to use updateOn and disabled together.

Comment: I am not using a form builder. It doesn't seem to matter what options are declared in the options object, the [object object] text appears unless I remove it completely.